# Spring-Test-Mvc Controller Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test-mvc

I'm using spring-test-mvc (standalone) because my application runs with spring 3.1. I'm basically just trying to test my controller methods and the response HTTP codes.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class AdminSpringControllerTests {
    private AdminSpringController cut;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    public AdminSpringControllerTests() {

        cut = new AdminSpringController();
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(cut).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void testGetUsers_Sc200_1() throws Exception{

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (int i = 1; i<3; i++) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(i);
            user.setUserId("test"+i);
            user.setName("Max Testermann");

            users.add(user);
        }

        EasyMock.expect(cut.userService.getUsers()).andReturn(users);
        EasyMock.replay();

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/user");

        this.mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

        EasyMock.verify(cut);

    }
}
```

But I'm getting an NoSuchMethodError

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManager.saveOutputFlashMap(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    at org.springframework.test.web.server.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.buildRequest(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:605)
    at org.springframework.test.web.server.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:125)
    at com.prime_sign.admin.web.controller.AdminSpringControllerTests.testGetUsers_Sc200_1(AdminSpringControllerTests.java:98)
```

Is it necessary to @Autowire my Controller? Is my constructor wrong ?
There is a context file in src/test/resources/"package-path"/AdminSpringControllerTests-context.xml but it only contains `<context:annotation-config />` and `<tx:annotation-driven />`, do I have to inject my controller bean there (question 1, is it necessary).

Thx for any help :)

**// EDIT**

I updated my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class AdminSpringControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    public AdminSpringControllerTests() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUsers_Sc200_1() throws Exception{

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (int i = 1; i<3; i++) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(i);
            user.setUserId("test"+i);
            user.setName("Max Testermann");

            users.add(user);
        }

        EasyMock.expect(cut.userService.getUsers()).andReturn(users);
        EasyMock.replay();

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/user").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        this.mockMvc.perform(request).andDo(print()).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

        EasyMock.verify(cut);

    }
}
```

But know I have the problem that (I think), I'm not getting the WebApplicationContext right:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.web.server.setup.InitializedContextMockMvcBuilder.<init>(InitializedContextMockMvcBuilder.java:39)
```

Comment: The root cause is a spring version issue. Post the version of each spring jar you are using.

Comment: spring-test-mvc 1.0.0.M2; easyMock 3.1 and spring 3.1.0;

Comment: All your Spring library versions should be the same. In this case, probably `3.1.0`.

Comment: thats correct; in spring 3.1.0 spring-test-mvc wasn't implemented like in 3.2 and therefor I used the stand alone project (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc)

Comment: would my debug console output be any help ? Wasn't able to fix the problem...

Comment: I am having similar problems. As soon as a `TestExecutionListener` is added to a working system, `WebApplicationContext is required` is thrown. Perhaps that can form an MVCE for a new question?

Comment: `saveOutputFlashMap()` was added to `FlashMapManager` in Spring 3.1.1 - it does not exist in Spring 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

you are using standaloneSetup and create your controller by using new AdminSpringController(); so spring doesnt have any control over it. Using standaloneSetup is more convenient to test just one controller at once, without any connection to filters/interceptors etc... which is probably not what you are looking for. Try to use webAppContextSetup instead:

```
....
 @Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}
```

this way it should use your spring configuration.

Comment: I'm using spring 3.1 and WebApplicationContext (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html) is within spring since 3.2

Comment: WebAppConfiguration annotation is since 3.2, WebApplicationContext is now 13 years old :)

Comment: Ok. but I'm using 3.1 :)

Comment: but you dont need @WebAppConfiguration ; )

Comment: Ok. So I autowire the WebApplicationContext and `mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(wac).build();`. but then I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required`. I think I'm getting so basic stuff wrong.

Comment: Also do I have to load a Context ? `@ContextConfiguration(loader=WebContextLoader.class,classes={WebConfig.class})` because I do not have any Webcontext atm. I just hava my "kinda" core project with my dao,service and controller methods
  
  v

Comment: yes you have to load it for tests, so MockMvcBuilders class will know how to build your test instance. Provide your spring xml configuration file in @ContextConfiguration(locations = "path.xml")

Comment: I already did that and loaded it with default param "classname"-context.xml.